# How to use vim-fugitive with a git bare repository?

Tags: vim, git-bare, vim-fugitive

### Environment

#### Setup

I use a *git bare* repository to version my *config* files. I can use same commands as if I were using a normal *git* repository just have to include some *flags*:

```sh
git --git-dir=/home/kunzaatko/.cfg/ --work-tree=/home/kunzaatko/ __command__
```

instead of

```sh
git __command__
```

#### Usage

I make use of *vim-fugitive* with normal *git* repositories mainly for making a big change and adding it in many different commits by staging partially (only a discrete set of hunks/changes) and committing them separately . I use `:Gdiff` for this for the nice and productive interface I can make use of.

### Desire

I want to do this with my config git bare repository.

#### What I tried:

1. Renaming the repository to `.cfg.git`. This didn't make any change. [issue that suggests this should work](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/117)
2. I tried to change the `b:git_dir` internal variable of *git-fugitive*:

```
:let b:git_dir=/home/kunzaatko/.cfg/
```

3. Changing the working directory to the git directory for fugitive to recognize that it is a git repo:

```
:chdir /home/kunzaatko/.cfg/
```

#### What would be worthy of trying if I knew how:

1. I think that there may be a way to use the `git submodule` command to put the bare repo into scope. The problem with that is where to put the *root* of the *git repository*... [issue that I base this possibility of of](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/139)

## Question

Is there a way to use a *git bare* repository with *git-fugitive*?

(or any other suggestion that would solve my use-case)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with @okket, but there is a problem when I use that method.

When in Gstatus window, I cannot get the status of changed files. And I find [the reason](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/415) is that fugitive gets the `core.worktree` attribute from the `GIT_DIR` repository.

So for me, the viable way to do this is as follows:

1. Same as @okket says, set `GIT_DIR` env variable when using vim/nvim command (`GIT_WORK_TREE` may be omitted):

```sh
GIT_DIR=$HOME/.cfg GIT_WORK_TREE=$HOME [n]vim
```

For users of fish shell (like me), should use `env` command:

```
env GIT_DIR=$HOME/.cfg GIT_WORK_TREE=$HOME [n]vim
```

2. Set `core.worktree` for your git repository:

```sh
git --git-dir=$HOME/.cfg --work-tree=$HOME config --local core.worktree $HOME
```

You can make sure you get it right with the following command:

```sh
git --git-dir=$HOME/.cfg --work-tree=$HOME config --local core.worktree
```

The output should be your HOME path.

3. If you get the git repository by `git clone --bare ...`, you need to unset `core.bare` to avoid git status error `warning: core.bare and core.worktree do not make sense`:

```sh
git --git-dir=$HOME/.cfg --work-tree=$HOME config --unset core.bare
```

And there is one more thing to notice for this method. You cannot use fugitive outside of `$HOME` directory where you will get `fugitive: working directory does not belong to a Git repository` error.

> PS: I'd like to comment on @okket 's answer, but due to low reputation I can only post a new answer here.

Answer (score 3):

The environment variables `$GIT_DIR` and `$GIT_WORK_TREE` let you point git and fugitive to the dotfile directory when using a bare repository. This solution works with the caveat, that fugitive/git will ignore other repositories while these variables are set.

To limit this environment pollution start vim like this:

```
GIT_DIR=$HOME/.cfg GIT_WORK_TREE=$HOME vim [file(s)]
```

In case the syntax is unfamiliar: it is possible to prepend setting environment variables before calling a binary in most (all?) shells. This limits redirecting git through the environment variables to this specific vim instance.

A quality of life improvement would be to put this line into a shell alias or use a full featured dotfile manager like [yadm](https://yadm.io/docs/getting_started), which is a wrapper around a git bare repository.